# Is there an elegant way for these arrows to automatically adjust to the color of the line segment they are in?

Tags: plotting

I added some arrows on a line:

```
pts = {{3, 2}, {2, 6}, {4, 2}, {0, 5}, {5, 0}, {0, 2}, {4, 5}, {2, 
    1}, {3, 5}};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[Table[0.05, 10]], 
  Arrow[Line[pts, 
    VertexColors -> Table[Hue[i/Length[pts]], {i, Length[pts]}]]]}]
```

[image]

But I found that the arrows were all **black**, and I didn't know how to adjust the arrows so that they were the same color as the line segments. Is there an easy way I've overlooked?

Comment: maybe `Graphics[{MapIndexed[{Arrowheads[.05], vc[[#2[[1]]]], 
      Arrow[{First@#, First@# + .01 (Subtract @@ #)}]} &]@
   Partition[pts, 2, 1], Line[pts, VertexColors -> vc]}]`?

Comment: ... where `vc = Table[Hue[i/Length[pts]], {i, Length[pts]}];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the requirement *"elegant"*

```
ClearAll[coloredArrowheads]

coloredArrowheads[t_ : .8, ah_ : .05, δ_ : .001] := 
 MapApply[{Blend[#2, t], Arrowheads[ah], 
     Arrow[{{1 - t + δ, t - δ} . #, {1 - t - δ, t + δ} . #}, 2 δ]} &] @
   Transpose[Map[Partition[#, 2, 1] &] @ {##}] &
```

***Examples:***

```
pts = {{3, 2}, {2, 6}, {4, 2}, {0, 5}, {5, 0}, {0, 2}, {4, 5}, {2, 1}, {3, 5}};

vc = Table[Hue[i/Length[pts]], {i, Length[pts]}];

Graphics[{Thick, Line[pts, VertexColors -> vc], 
  coloredArrowheads[][pts, vc]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Thick, Line[pts, VertexColors -> vc],
  coloredArrowheads[.2][pts, vc], 
  coloredArrowheads[][pts, vc]}]
```

[image]

```
rp = {{0, 0}, {1, .5}};
rc = {Red, Blue};

Graphics[{Thick, Line[rp, VertexColors -> rc],
  coloredArrowheads[#][rp, rc] & /@ Subdivide[9]}]
```

[image]